# Flutter Dropdown slider from Appbar

Tags: flutter

I want to archive some kind of dropdown look like the image. I tried to find but I don't get any.
Please help.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visibility Widget . You put it on top and hide it until you need it

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html